# How to adjust size of inverter in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to reduce the size of the inverter default in circuitikz but I fail to find the right `ctikzset` command.

```
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (10,0) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s1c1) {}

    (05,2) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s2cr1) {}
    (10,6) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s2cr2) {}

    (03,4) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s2c1) {}
    (09,8) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s2c2) {}

    (2,6) node[not port, rotate = 90] (s3c1) {}
    (4,6) node[not port, rotate = 90] (s3c2) {}
    (7,7) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s3c3) {}
    (7,9) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s3c4) {}

    (s1c1.out) |- (s2cr1.in)
    (s1c1.out) |- (s2cr2.in)

    (s2cr1.out) -| (s2c1.in)
    (s2cr2.out) |- (s2c2.in)

    (s2c1.out) -| (s3c1.in)
    (s2c1.out) -| (s3c2.in)

    (s2c2.out) |- (s3c3.in)
    (s2c2.out) |- (s3c4.in)

    (s3c1.out) -- (s3c2.out)
    (s3c2.out) -| (s3c3.out)
    (s3c3.out) -- (s3c4.out)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

The man page seems to have entries for NAND gates:

```
\ctikzset{tripoles/american nand port/input height=.2}
\ctikzset{tripoles/american nand port/port width=.2}
```

based on that, I tried interpolating it to inverters:

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/american not port/input height=.2}
```

In place of `bipoles`, I also tried `tripoles`,`double bipoles` based on the man page but I am unable to control the size.

Here is how my output looks and I would like to use significantly smaller inverters for my work:

[image: Large inveters :(]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much documentation on these parameters. You have to find the source code and search it.  My editor has a "Find in files..." option which I have set to search all the files in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/not port/height=.2}
\ctikzset{bipoles/not port/width=.2}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (10,0) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s1c1) {}

    (05,2) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s2cr1) {}
    (10,6) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s2cr2) {}

    (03,4) node[not port, rotate = 090] (s2c1) {}
    (09,8) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s2c2) {}

    (2,6) node[not port, rotate = 90] (s3c1) {}
    (4,6) node[not port, rotate = 90] (s3c2) {}
    (7,7) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s3c3) {}
    (7,9) node[not port, rotate = 180] (s3c4) {}

    (s1c1.out) |- (s2cr1.in)
    (s1c1.out) |- (s2cr2.in)

    (s2cr1.out) -| (s2c1.in)
    (s2cr2.out) |- (s2c2.in)

    (s2c1.out) -| (s3c1.in)
    (s2c1.out) -| (s3c2.in)

    (s2c2.out) |- (s3c3.in)
    (s2c2.out) |- (s3c4.in)

    (s3c1.out) -- (s3c2.out)
    (s3c2.out) -| (s3c3.out)
    (s3c3.out) -- (s3c4.out)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I tried doing this in Windows and it works but weirdly, it does not work in my Unix machine. But the solution is right though.

Comment: It may be a function of how recently you updated your packages.